# How to manage Facebook api response data in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

How to convert facebook api response in user readable HTML format?

I call graph api 
[https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=<token>](https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=%3Ctoken%3E)

below is my response data from API.

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "100000626589435_240877109276507",
         "from": {
            "name": "Abhi Patel",
            "id": "100000626589435"
         },
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2011-08-02T10:36:17+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-08-02T10:36:17+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "100000626589435_240760105954874",
         "from": {
            "name": "Abhi Patel",
            "id": "100000626589435"
         },
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2011-08-02T03:02:21+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-08-02T03:02:21+0000"
      },       
      {
         "id": "100000626589435_223775454320006",
         "from": {
            "name": "Abhi Patel",
            "id": "100000626589435"
         },
         "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/274314_100000898272591_5481895_q.jpg",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/?ref=nf_fr",
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/icons/?8:",
         "type": "link",
         "created_time": "2011-06-28T18:56:44+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-06-28T18:56:44+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "<previous link>",
      "next": "<next link>"
   }
}
```

also want **paging in facebook response data**,
I want 20 records from facebook api response. 
How to manage this things..

Answer (score 0):

Facebook returns raw JSON data. There are no style elements to it. It's up to you to present the data returned in the format you choose. Imagine if Facebook returned HTML and style elements. That wouldn't work very well for desktop applications or mobile devices. Instead, they just give you the raw data, and you design the HTML elements, or the WPF Views, or whatever to show the data you want to show.

By returning the raw data, you can also store it locally in a database for your own queries, or your own applications purposes.

Edited to add: You can parse out the objects by accessing the JSON elements directly, or you can deserialize the result to C# objects.

```
Console.WriteLine(response.data[0].from.name);
```

As for paging, you need to parse out the Paging elements. The Facebook C# SDK returns dynamic objects, so you can do something like

```
string next = response.paging.next;
string prev = response.paging.prev;
```

And then just make a request to each URL to fetch the data you want.

Comment: Hello @mfanto, How to generate <div>Username : </div> <div> <response Username> </div>.. like this.. I want to convert in Html format in C#. How I can convert from this plain text. please suggest me.

Comment: I have no idea how you should generate it. Only you can answer based on how your site/application works. How I do it is I deserialize the response, convert it to a viewmodel, and display it using an ASP.NET MVC view that has the appropriate stylesheets. You have the response, and there's an example of how to read an element. The Facebook C# SDK also includes ASP.NET sample applications you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and convert into the XML then it would be easy to manage for you.

Comment: There's no need to convert to XML. He already has the data in JSON. He can either access the attributes directly, or he can deserialize it to a POCO.